# Rails form_for doesn't populate fields with values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to use `form_for` with a non-activerecord model.

The problem is that the `value` of the fields is not initialized properly: it is always blank, even if the attribute is present.

For example this works:

```
@customer = Customer.retrieve_from_api(id)
@customer.billing_address.first_name # => "Marco"
```

But the form isn't initialized properly:

```
<%= form_for @customer, as: :customer, url: billing_info_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :billing_address do |b| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%# this is always blank (i.e. the initial value of the field is "") %>
      <%= b.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
```

BTW I know that I could use `form_tag`, `text_field_tag` and initialize the value explicitly, but I would like to avoid that and keep the code DRY since I have many fields

Comment: Post the .rb file handling this virtual attribute

Comment: @bkunzi01 The Customer object is this: https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-ruby/blob/master/lib/chargebee/models/customer.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass `@customer.billing_address` as an argument to `f.fields_for` to make it work:

```
<%= f.fields_for :billing_address, @customer.billing_address do |b| %>
```